# App authenticity is giving a different error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement app authenticity on android native app. It works fine I am able to get fail on app authenticity failure .. But the problem is I am getting an error saying .

> Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.

But what I am expecting is. I was seeing this error before yesterday, But from yesterday I am seeing "Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.". I took an update can that be a cause.

> app authenticity security check failed

And I am also seeing below error, even before fail is being called.

> > 07-27 05:30:02.392 15664-15664/com.ds I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
> >     07-27 05:30:02.392
> >     15664-15664/com.ds I/MultiDex: install
> >      07-27 05:30:02.392
> >     15664-15664/com.ds I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex
> >     support library is disabled.
> >     07-27 05:30:02.448 15664-15686/com.ds
> >     W/com.worklight.common.Logger:
> >     com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Context) must be called to
> >     fully enable debug log capture.  Currently, the 'capture' flag is set
> >     but the 'context' field is not.  This warning will only be printed
> >     once.
> >     07-27 05:30:03.493 15664-15670/com.ds W/art:
> >     Suspending all threads took: 149.185ms

Comment: Can you provide wireshark log of the network communication when the failure is happing? Did you try to reinstall the application?

Comment: I am sorry I don't have setup of wireshark.... I cant download it... Yup I unistalled installed it back and  used a  complete new emulator also.

Comment: Try to get wireshark working. The logs are critical for debugging.

Comment: Ok I will try to get it. But any guess why this can happen. Is there any chance if a logger class is called before wlconnect method this could happen.

Comment: Unlikely to be the cause.

Comment: Any updates to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I was checking the value(App authenticity failure message) by
   calling **wlFailResponse.getErrorMsg()** which was giving me
   **"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again."**
2. But the actual value(App authenticity failure message) that i am looking for
   was in **wlFailResponse.getResponseJSON().getString("reason").**